# Investigate impact of one variable in the present of another

Tags: regression, normal-distribution, effect-size

In my project analysis, I am currently investigate the impact of the ambient temperature on vitamin D level. I am using parametric tests as I transformed the Vit D data to meet the assumption of normally distribution. I conducted regression and found that with increase temperature the Vit D level increases.

Now, I need to see who is affected more male or female? Mean, is there any impact of temperature to reflects different Vit D level between gender? Or males or females were more effected by weather in Vit D level?
What is the test for this or how to conduct it?

I would appreciate any help as I am beginner in statistics.

Answer (score 1):

Your current model is $$ Y=\beta_0 + \beta_1 X_1 + \epsilon$$ where $X_1 $ = temperature.
Next you can add gender ($X_2$) and the interaction between gender and temperature ($X_1X_2$) in the model, i.e., $$ Y=\beta_0 + \beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 X_2 +\beta_3 X_1X_2 +\epsilon$$
Next to check if $\beta_3$ is significantly differ from zero. If yes, the effects of temperature on Vitamin D are different between male and female; otherwise, the effects are the same.